# Should I keep my SqlConnection open when dealing with asynchronous code via APM?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, ado.net

I'm creating an application (it's a server) that uses a socket to receive data from different clients (a chat server) and has access to a database (Microsoft SQL Server).

The server update loop looks like something like this:

```
void UpdateLoop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        ReceiveData();
        ProcessData();
    }
}
```

Each time I receive a data (a string) from a client, this data will be saved to the database, using a stored procedure. Since it's single threaded and I want to avoid blocking operations, I opted to use the Asynchronous Programming Model (APM):

```
void ProcessData()
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("stored_procedure_name", _connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(CommandCallback, command);
    /*at this point, we return to the UpdateLoop method and
      the command keeps running asynchronously, avoid blocking
      the whole thread and processing other requests.*/
}

void CommandCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var command = (SqlCommand)ar.AsyncState;
    command.EndExecuteNonQuery(ar);
}
```

As you can see above, the **_connection** variable represents the *SqlConnection* class, which holds the connection to the database. I open the connection at the start of the application and I only close it at the end of the application.

I've read that it's better (and a good coding practice) to open the connection only when needed and disposing it immediately after the use, with the *using* statement, just like this:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    //create the command and execute it (synchronously)
}
```

But I (think) can't use the *using* statement with my current code, since it must be asynchronous.

Is is ok to let the sql connection open the whole time? If not, what's the better solution for this case?

Comment: It's usually not a big deal to leave the connection established, as long as it's just sitting idle and not, say, leaving a transaction open. There is a non-zero cost associated with establishing a connection to the database so if you're doing heavy traffic, closing and re-opening connections thousands of times a minute is going to start to be noticeable.  In that scenario, it's decidedly better to leave the connections established.

Comment: Dispose of your resources as soon as you are finished with them.  Sql Connection pool will take care of prioritising for you as soon as you need to re-establish a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is clear: open connection and close it ASAP ;) of course in short. I've done pretty similar chat to yours recently and I dont care about connection. I open it when I need and I close it after getting data. The main reason is that when application opens connection in fact it don't realy... open it. Strange? Not really. There is something like connection pool where are coulpe of connections ready to use. Physically opening connection to db takes a long time therefore mentioned pool has been "invented". If your chat would be more and more popular try to switch websockets.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But how do I close the connection in my case since it's asynchronous (APM)? Should I close the connection on the CommandCallback method? And what if there are thousands of requests being processed at the same time?